# Unexpected Data::Dumper::Dumper result

Tags: perl

Why does here [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper)::Dumper print the `$VAR1->{'AA'}[2]` instead of `{ 1 => 6 }`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;

my @a = ( 'a', 'b', { 1 => 6 } );
my %h = (
    'AA' => [ @a ],
    'BB' => [ @a ],
);


say $h{BB}->[2]{1};

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper \%h;
```

Output:

```
6
$VAR1 = {
        'AA' => [
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    {
                    '1' => 6
                    }
                ],
        'BB' => [
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    $VAR1->{'AA'}[2]
                ]
        };
```

Comment: You are attempting to copy values, but one of your values is a reference: `{ 1 => 6 }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example `$VAR1->{'AA'}[2]` and `$VAR1->{'BB'}[2]` are references to the same hash.

[`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) does not want to print a variable more than once. This behaviour represents the data structure more faithfully, and it avoids any infinite loop it might encounter.
e.g.:

```
my $loop;
$loop = { 1 => \$loop };
print Dumper $loop;
```

Output is

```
$VAR1 = {
     '1' => \$VAR1
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`Data::Dumper` has [configuration variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods) that can change the behavior that avoids printing a reference more than once.

> - `$Data::Dumper::Deepcopy` or `$OBJ->Deepcopy([NEWVAL])`
>
>   Can be set to a boolean value to enable deep copies of structures. Cross-referencing will then only be done when absolutely essential (i.e., to break reference cycles). Default is 0.

To integrate this into your script just localize the variable:

```
say do {
    local $Data::Dumper::Deepcopy = 1;
    Dumper \%h;
};
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AA' => [
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    {
                      '1' => 6
                    }
                  ],
          'BB' => [
                    'a',
                    'b',
                    {
                      '1' => 6
                    }
                  ]
        };
```